# How to replace "a" tag with "img" using regex in php?

Tags: php, html, regex, anchor, href

```
<div class="media_embed" height="qqq" width="www">
<a href="http://giphy.com/gifs/dancing">via GIPHY</a>
<div class="media_embed" height="eee" width="rrr">
<a href="http://giphy.com/gifs/movie">via GIPHY</a>
```

i want  to do this:
i have to get de `href` from anchor tag and put it bewtween `img` tags and add `figure` tag

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://giphy.com/gifs/dancing" />
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://giphy.com/gifs/movie" />
</figure>
```

can you please help me

Comment: Don't use regex, use a parser.

Comment: Please mark my answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is parsing html and then change it. You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse html. But if you want to use regex, use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace `a` tag with another tag.

```
echo preg_replace("/<a href=\"(.*)\">.*<\/a>/", "<figure><img src='$1' /></figure>", $html)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/IULpA)